# AWS Lambda triggered by S3 event not firing when file is uploaded programmatically via another Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, lambda

I have an AWS setup where a post Lambda function uploads an image to an S3 bucket. I also have another Lambda function that is supposed to be triggered whenever a new image is uploaded to this S3 bucket.

Here's the sequence of events:

1. Image data is received in a post Lambda function.
2. The post Lambda processes this data and uploads the image to an S3 bucket.
3. Another Lambda function should be triggered by the S3 ObjectCreated event to process this image.

However, I am facing an issue where the second Lambda is not being triggered when the image is uploaded programmatically via the post Lambda. If I manually upload an image to the S3 bucket through the AWS console, the second Lambda triggers as expected. This lambda is written in python and uses the boto3 sdk.

```
    object_key = None
    if "image" in thread:
        image_data = base64.b64decode(thread["image"].split(',')[1])
        content_type = thread.get("contentType", "image/jpeg")
        # Validate the content type
        if content_type not in ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]:
            raise ValueError("Invalid content type")
        # Extracts 'jpeg', 'png', or 'gif' from the MIME type
        extension = content_type.split("/")[-1]
        object_key = f"{board_id}/{thread_id}/image.{extension}"

        s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=object_key,
                             Body=image_data, ContentType=content_type)
```

This is part of my post lambda, this post lambda works and has been tested for quite long.

```
 this.processor.addEventSource(
      new event_sources.S3EventSource(this.dataSource, {
        events: [s3.EventType.OBJECT_CREATED],
      })
    );
```

This is part of the CDK code I have written.
Things I've verified:

- The S3 bucket has the correct event notifications set up.
- IAM permissions are set correctly, allowing the S3 bucket to trigger the Lambda.
- Manual uploads to the S3 bucket trigger the Lambda function correctly.
- The post Lambda works without any errors and uploads images to S3 successfully.

Does anyone have any idea why the processing Lambda doesn't trigger when the image is uploaded programmatically, and how I can resolve this?

###### added

IAM permissions to the lambda that should be triggered whenever a new image is uploaded.

- AmazonS3FullAccess
- AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
- AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole

Comment: Location of manually uploaded file and programmatically uploaded file is same?

Comment: You have enabled event on specific object or every object?

Comment: @RohitAgarwal Hi. Thanks! 
Yes, I have manually uploaded it in the same location as the programmatically uploaded file name. It worked when I manually did it. 
And also yes, I disabled the filter so that the event will be triggered for every object created in the targeted bucket.

Comment: Can you show us your IAM permissions? As it stands, this question isn't reproducible and it's a candidate for closure until we can reproduce it.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary 
hi. I edited the body to add the IAM permissions.

Comment: Can you just confirm what event notification you're using for your S3 event trigger? What you can use is s3:ObjectCreated:*, just to confirm it works and then reduce it after.

The only other thing I can think of is maybe KMS permissions if you've set any?

Comment: s3:ObjectCreated:* Yes I use that to trigger my events. 
I do not have any KMS permissions set.